# Only let certain inner divs control outer div's width

Tags: html, css

I have the follow html structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1">
        <img src="someimage/path" />
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
        Some Text
    </div>
    <div id="block3">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

the container is `float:left`.  The container will stretch out to the widest div, but what if i only want it to follow block1, and have block2 and block3's text to wrap according to how big the image in block1 is.  For my markup right now, if the text is long it will push out the container div as far as the text goes out, but I want the text to only be as wide as the image, almost like an image caption.  Any ideas?

Comment: you are missing a clossing </div> for block3 is that a typo or is it also in your code?

Comment: I would try making block2 and block 3 as `position:relative` ( so they are out of flow and not take any space, so they wouldn't push the boundary )

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the container `display:inline-block;` with `overflow:auto;` so that it automatically stretches to fit the content. Give Block #2 and Block #3 `overflow:auto;` too so that they stretch to fit their content.

Unfortunately, you need to use JavaScript to get the width to be the width of the image. See my example below, where I fix it with jQuery.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/2

Comment: I think the point is that the width of the image is unknown, or maybe I'm just seeing things more complicated than they are :)

Comment: Doesn't matter--it'll still work. :) The fixed width in my CSS is just to demonstrate. Make it any size you want.

Comment: it doesn't work if the container doesn't have set width, block 2 and 3 will stretch the container.

Comment: Look at my code. The container *doesn't* have a fixed width. :)

Comment: Hmmm, now that I understand the author's question, I don't actually know how to do this without JavaScript. Great question, sir!