# Outer div to match inner div's width

Tags: html, css

I have made a sketch so it is easier for me to explain the problem:
[image: sketch]
<sub>(source: [mielai.lt](http://www.mielai.lt/sketch.png))</sub>

So, as you understand three colored rectangles are divs, red rectangle is container, green div has the logo and the other stuff, blue div has thumbnails wrapped in li tags. All divs are on auto width. Thumbnails are floating, so the wider the screen is, the more thumbnails are in a row dynamically, but there is always left space in the right side because it is too narrow for one more thumb to get there.

I would like the blue div to have the width close to where thumbs end, where the blue dotted line is, and it should change dynamically.

Second thing is the green div, ideally i would like it to match the widt of the blue div where it ends as the dotted line, so the stuff in green div won't step out of the whole look.

Is these possible to make? If yes, please explain how, or give examples.

I have tried various things myself including various examples ([Only let certain inner divs control outer div's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215670/only-let-certain-inner-divs-control-outer-divs-width)) but they don't work for me.

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting the position of the red div to relative, and then set the position of the blue and green div to absolute, and give them a left:0, and a width:100%, tell me what you get. Also, it would be helpfull if you posted your markup on a jsFiddle.

Comment: Are you hoping to support IE or browsers that don't support `display: flexbox`?

Comment: please make the code show us your demo here :- http://tinkerbin.com/

Comment: have you tried using bootstrap's scaffolding? it could simplify matters for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you have to use JavaScript to do that (or it is at least very easy to do in JavaScript).
Using jQuery for example you can do the following:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var original_blue_width = $("#red").width() - 2*3;
    var blue_width = original_blue_width - (original_blue_width % (10+5));
    $("#blue").width (blue_width);
    $("#green").width (blue_width);
});
```

where 3 is the padding between the red and the blue boxes, 5 is the padding between the thumbnails and 10 is the width of a thumbnail.
Please ask/comment if something is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, i tried that but it didn't work. My divs are classes, not IDs, but i tried to rename them to IDs without luck. Also my thumbs are wrapped with <li></li> with extra css styling: padding, borders, etc. Maybe that caused the non working of the script? I did change the thumb width and paddings in your example.

Comment: if the divs are classes just use $(".red") instead of $("#red")
You also have to include jQuery for this example to work.
Could you maybe upload your code to tinkerbin.com as Shailender Arora proposed?

Answer (score 3):

i fixed such situation with:

```
float:left;
```

to the outer DIV;

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/8fgjs/3/)

**Step 1:** Calculate the actual width of thumb box i.e. width + 2*(border + margin + padding)

**Step 2:** Calculate no of thumb in a row (this is where you have to think) what 
        I have done is   that i have checked the top of every thumb See Function
        **calculate_in1Row ()**

HTML:

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="green">Logo</div>
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS :

```
.red {border:1px solid red; }
.green{border:1px solid green; margin:2px;}
.blue{border:1px solid blue; margin:2px; overflow:auto;}
.thumb {border:1px solid black; width:40px; height:40px; margin:2px; padding:3px;  float:left}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tw = $(".thumb").width() + 2 * (1 + 2 + 3); // width + 2*(border+margin + padding)
    tw = tw * calculate_in1Row()
    $(".blue").width(tw);
    $(".green").width(tw);
});

// function ti calculate no of thumb box in single row
function calculate_in1Row() {
    var in1Row = 0;
    $('.blue .thumb').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            in1Row++;
        }
        else {
            in1Row++;
        }
    });

    return in1Row;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Since question is not tagged javascript/jquery, the CSS solution can be as below:

What I would say is that you can create an outer div that surrounds the green and blue boxes. Give width to this outer div and have it set the property `margin:0 auto;` This will fit all the small black boxes surrounded at equal spaces from right and left.