# Keep outer div width from inner img, but not wider due to inner text

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <img id="imageDiv" src="file here" />
    <div id="innertext">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

I want the `#outerdiv` width to be defined by the image width. The image is of variable width.
The problem is that the text in `#innertext` expands `#outerdiv` to the full width of the page.

UPDATE:
Being a noob here I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet, but...

I got it working by adding a single line of jQuery.

```
$('#outerDiv').width($('#imageDiv').width());
```

Comment: Can you post your code attempt thus far please.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the `outerdiv`'s width equal zero, then the image will push it out if it needs too.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <img src="file here" width="50px" />
    <div id="innertext">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outerdiv {
    width:0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem in not getting the outerDiv wide enough, it's stopping it from getting wider than the image when more text is added to innerText.

Comment: well then it sounds like you want it to be the same size as the innertext?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should have said "the problem is not...". I want the outerDiv to be the width of the image (which is a variable size). The text should wrap itself underneath the image to the same with as the image. The problem was that the text was not wrapping until it had expanded outerDiv to the width of the screen.

Comment: the text does wrap under the image with the example above, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

So your major problem is about the #innertext, right?
I think you could try to fix #innertext as a portion to the #outerdiv, so that #innertext will depend on the size of #outerdiv instead of pushing it out, simply as like this:

```
#innertext{
 width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: I'd already tried that, but it doesn't work. The problem appears to be because outerDiv doesn't have a fixed width.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215670/only-let-certain-inner-divs-control-outer-divs-width?rq=1, which has been answered, but doesn't work. The concept that the width needs setting via js seems reasonable though.

Comment: @Headforthehills oh, right, in that case, it might not work. Glad you found the solution later.